# read if it matches/contains the voters number in text file

Tags: java, text, file-handling

for example my text file contains this:

```
1/hannah/18
2/jeorge/20
```

the arrangement is like `votersnumber/name/age` now i want my program to read the file, determine if the `votersnumber` from the text file contains what the user entered as his voters number then execute the following procedure. if the file doesn't contain/match what the user entered, the program will make the user input a voters number again.

i tried doing that by this codes:

```
File Orig_outFile = new File("C:\\Users/Regz-pc/workspace/lozada/voters.txt");
    BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Orig_outFile));

    String voters[]=new String[10+1]; //purpose of this is to determine whether the voter already voted. the [10+1] is not final but just a sample/just for test. but i will still be using this
    String allVoters="";
    for(int index=1;index<voters.length;index++){
        voters[index]="NOT VOTED YET";
        allVoters=allVoters+"voter["+index+"]="+voters[index]+"\n";
        }

    vNum2=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter voters number: "));//user will enter the voters number
    vNum=Integer.toString(vNum2);
    String line=null;

    while((line=infile.readLine())!=null){
        String [] info=line.split("/");//divide the votersnumber/name/age
        if(!info[0].contains(vNum) && voters[vNum2].contains("VOTER ALREADY VOTED")){//determine if the vNum2 exist in text file
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Voter already voted or Voter not registered. Please try again");
                vNum2=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter voters number: "));
                }
        else{
            voters[vNum2]="VOTER ALREADY VOTED";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, allVoters);

            President();
        }
    }
    infile.close();
```

but this code will only execute once, but then after it will execute the error message `Voter already voted or Voter not registered. Please try again` will appear and then will make the user input a voter's number again and then will go back to the main menu. and when i tried executing this program again, it will just let me enter a voter's number and then after that will go back to the main menu.

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid java condition,

```
while((line=infile.readLine())!=null){
```

use this instead:

```
while(infile.readLine() != null){
```

and read the line:

```
String line= "";
while(infile.readLine() !=null){
    // read the line
    line=infile.readLine()

    // res of your code...
}
```

Comment: oh this works on my problems about the President() executing only once, now it works thank you so much :) but do you know what should i do to determine if the entered voters number exist in the text text file?

Comment: @bruh I don't understand what you mean with *what should i do to determine if the entered voters number exist in the text text file?*

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!info[0].contains(vNum) && voters[vNum2].contains("VOTER ALREADY VOTED")){//determine if the vNum2 exist in text file
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Voter already voted or Voter not registered. Please try again");
    vNum2=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter voters number: "));
}
```

Here, you need to change vNum as well, i think.

Comment: umm nothing really changed :/ but can you suggest anything on how to edit the vNum?

Comment: I've just noticed, that you're using both variables in if-statement, so if you're changing vNum2, you should change vNum as well, like: vNum=Integer.toString(vNum2);

Comment: Inside the while loop?

Comment: oh i did move my vNum=Integer.toString(vNum2)  inside the while loop now. but it's still the same nothing happened  :/ can i use while instead of if-else tho?

Comment: If you use a while, you will be entering the voter number over and over (for each line in file), while finally you will enter the exact number of the voter.

Comment: Btw, why "contains" not "equals"?

Comment: oh it is really the same :( i tried all you've suggested and i didn't use while as well. but it is really the same nothing changed :(